# What are my technical requirements?

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-services, microservices, windows-server-2012-r2

My goal is to build an application that can dynamically monitor my Stock Portfolio (Stock Options actually).  So, I am building my business logic in a TDD approach using C# on .NET core.  I haven't much thought about the interface because the following is true:

1) My broker is ETrade so I will have to authenticate and use their api for my position information

2) I need this application to run from 9:30 AM - 4:00 PM EST Monday - Friday

As I am nearing completion of my 1st MVP business logic, I am now starting to think about where I will delpoy the final solution and hence I am seeking the community for feedback.

I have heard, but not worked much with Microservices (AWS, Azure, etc.) so I'm not sure if that is the direction I want to look.  (Also, I have a tight timeline and don't want to have to learn too much to get this thing deployed - but I am open to any solution).  Excluding Microservices and the Cloud I have considered the following:

### a) "I could run the program from a Console application"?

**(answer)** I would have to either:

(a) get a dedicated server to do or

(b) try to ensure that I can leave a laptop running at home or something, blah, blah

**(conclusion)** Both are plausible decisions.

### b) "I could run the program as a Windows Service"

**(answer)** I would have to either

(a) (same as above)

(b) (same as above)

**(conclusion)** Both are plausible decisions.

### c) "I could run the program as a Web Site"

**(answer)** I would have to either

(a) (same as above)

(b) (same as above)

**(conclusion)** Both are plausible decisions.

### c) "I could investigate The Cloud (Microservices)"

**(answer)** ???
**(conclusion)**

So, in closing, basically, given the requirements of up-time between those hours and I would like to be able to access the app from any internet browser.  I have logic that needs to ping various endpoints pretty much every minute during market hours.  So I am not sure how I would handle this using a Web Application because if (by chance) the browser is closed, the Web Application stops running and thus would defeat my needs!  Does the cloud help here?  Maybe I should just use a Windows Service and make my logs accessible on the web.  Or I deploy the TraderBot in a Windows Service and also build a Web Application to receive real-time intel from the TraderBot Windows Service / Logs /  and-or DB?  Not sure, but I appreciate any knee-jerk responses you all have!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like to connect pieces of tech to solve complex problems. Though it's not that complex.

1. Solution 1: Cloud-based, specifically on AWS
   Use AWS [Lambdas](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)(Serverless compute) to hit the API to get prices or whatever info you are seeking and then store it in [DynamoDb](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/)(A NoSQL DB). Use [CloudWatch Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)(Serverless CRON job) to invoke your lambda periodically.
   Then SPA Single page application to view values stored in DynamoDb. It can be a [static website hosted on S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) also.
   Or
   A mobile app can also serve the purpose of viewing the data from DynamoDb.
2. Solution 2: Mobile-Only
   Why not build the app purely for mobiles like iOS or Android. Check [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.raevilman.bitcoinpriceindianexchanges) I've coded one app just to track the price of different alt-coins of different exchanges.
   With the mobile-only app, your app will fetch the prices periodically(Using alarms API in case of Android) and will store in its local database(SQLite in case of Android) and then you can open the app any time to see the latest values.

More solutions can be thought of, But I think above are a good approach for solving this problem rather than buying a VPS or blowing your laptop all 24X7 #ThinkCloud

PS: Initial thoughts only, Ask more to enhance the solution... :)